# Bootstrap 4: popover color

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

How do you fix the arrow color on bootstrap 4 popover?

[image]

This is my CSS:

```
.popover {
    background-color: #212121;
    color: $transparent_white;
}
```

this is my HTML:

```
<div class="popover bs-tether-element show bs-tether-element-attached-top bs-tether-element-attached-center bs-tether-target-attached-bottom bs-tether-target-attached-center" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; transform: translateX(243px) translateY(294px) translateZ(0px);">
    <div data-reactroot="" class="popover-inner">
        <div class="component-rate-popover popover-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way.

```
.popover.popover-bottom::after, 
.popover.bs-tether-element-attached-top::after{ border-bottom-color:#212121; }
```

Comment: This almost worked out of the box, but I had to make a small change to get it working:

.popover.popover-bottom::after, .popover.bs-tether-element-attached-top::after{
    border-bottom-color:#212121;
}

Maybe this is related to my popover being placed on bottom?

Comment: I updated my question, note that I solved it adding the code I comented above

Comment: please update your answer so I can mark it as correct :)

Comment: I did it, its not problem as long as your problem is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Sass (.SCSS), this works:

```
.bs-popover-bottom .arrow::after, .bs-popover-auto[x-placement^="bottom"] .arrow::after {
        border-bottom-color: #212121;
}
```